# What is opposite of "burzum", "darkness", in Tolkien's Black Speech?

Tags: tolkien-black-speech, phrase-request

I'm aware that *burzum* means *darkness* in [The Black Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech#The_One_Ring_inscription).

Do we know what the opposite is? How is *lightness* written?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a translation request, which I would like to consider off-scope

Comment: [Relevant meta discussion.](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/thoughts-on-this-question-translation-request)

Comment: I don't understand why is this question considered offtopic, since it is searching for a word that is *unknown*. Tolkien didn't provide much information about black speech, and this answering this question would require searching a lot for the data. And about the tags, [a relevant meta discussion](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/how-to-tag-different-worlds-languages-with-the-same-race-name)

Comment: @Adarain There's a [currently ongoing meta discussion](https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23/12) about questions of this type. At the moment, the highest-voted answer says to allow them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Darkgamma says, we don't know.  The closest we have would probably be **ghâsh**, which means fire, and one could probably guess that the characteristic of being fire-like would be something like **ghâshum**, but there is no empirical evidence for that, except that the suffix -um seems to mean -ness, as in **burz-** (meaning dark) + **-um** (meaning -ness), put together to form **burzum**.

That said, **ghâshum** would literally mean "the characteristic of being like fire," not literally "lightness."

Answer (score 10):

In short: no.

In a bit long: [not really, and some people have gone to the effort of analysing the Black Speech](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/orkish.htm). In essence, the list of words we know thus far is rather scant:

> agh "and"
>    ash "one"
>             -at infinitive suffix, or possibly a specialized "intentive" suffix indicating purpose: Ash nazg durbatulûk "one Ring to rule them all"
>             bagronk (DBS) "cesspool", possibly bag+ronk "cess+pool"
>             búbhosh (DBS) "great"
>             búrz "dark", (isolated from Lugbúrz, q.v.), burzum "darkness"
>             dug "filth", tentatively isolated from pushdug, q.v.
>             durb- "rule", infinitive durbat, only attested with suffixes: 
>      durbatulûk "to rule them all". The verb durb- is remarkably similar to Quenya tur- of similar sense. 
>             ghâsh "fire" (stated to be derived from the Black Speech, may or may not represent Sauron's original form of the word)
>             gimb- "find", infinitive gimbat, only attested with a pronominal suffix: gimbatul, "to find them"
>             glob (DBS) "fool"
>             gûl "any one of the major invisible servants of Sauron dominated entirely by his will" (A Tolkien Compass p. 172). Translated "wraith(s)" in the compound Nazgûl, "Ringwraith(s)".
>             hai "folk", in Uruk-hai "Uruk-folk" and Olog-hai "Troll-folk"; cf. also Oghor-hai.
>             ishi "in", a suffixed postposition: burzum-ishi, "in the darkness".
>             krimp- "bind", infinitive krimpat, only attested with a pronominal suffix: krimpatul, "to bind them"
>             lug "tower". Isolated from Lugbúrz, q.v.
>             Lugbúrz the Dark Tower, Sindarin Barad-dûr (Lug-búrz "Tower-dark")
>             nazg "ring": ash nazg "one ring", Nazgûl "Ring-wraith(s)"
>             Nazgûl "Ring-wraith(s)", nazg + gûl (q.v.)
>             Oghor-hai "Drúedain" (UT:379; this may or may not be pure Black Speech)
>             olog a variety of Troll apparently developed by Sauron. Olog-hai "Olog-people".
>             pushdug (DBS) "dungfilth", possibly push+dug "dung+filth"
>             ronk (DBS) "pool", tentatively isolated from bagronk, q.v.
>             skai (DBS) interjection of contempt
>             sha (DBS) interjection of contempt
>             sharkû (DBS?) "old man"
>             snaga "slave" (May be DBS.) Used of lesser breeds of Orcs (WJ:390).
>             thrak- "bring", infinitive thrakat, only attested with suffixes: thrakatulûk "to bring them all"
>             u (DBS) "to"
>             -ûk "all", suffixed to pronominal suffixes: -ulûk, "them all"
>             -ul pronominal suffix "them".
>             -um "-ness" in burzum "darkness". 
>             uruk a great variety of Orc. According to WJ:390, Sauron probably borrowed this word "from the Elvish tongues of earlier times".

The abbreviation *DBS* stands for *Debased Black Speech*, a colloquial idiom variety of the Black Speech as used by the orcs and goblins.